# How can I pass multiple file names with spaces to a command via strace?

Tags: bash, strace

I have a script that uses strace, cp, awk, and stat, to create a cp with a progress bar.  Here is the part of the code where it calls cp:

```
    strace -q -ewrite cp -- `printf '%q ' $@` 2>&1 | awk {Lots of code here}
```

The problem is, I cannot copy anything with a space.  How should I modify this script so it will work with spaces? Thanks

EDIT:  Here is the output:

```
matt: ~/tmp $ bash -x cp-progress "q" "file"
++ printf '%q ' q file
++ stat -c %s q
+ strace -q -ewrite cp -- q file
+ awk '{
        count += $NF
            if (count % 10 == 0) {
               percent = count / total_size * 100
               printf "%2d%% [", percent
               for (i=0;i<=percent / 2;i++)
                  printf "→"
               printf "→"

               printf "]\r"
            }
         }
         END { print "" }' total_size=5242880 count=0
100% [→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→]
matt: ~/tmp $ bash -x cp-progress "q" "file with spaces"
++ printf '%q ' q 'file with spaces'
+ strace -q -ewrite cp -- q 'file\' 'with\' spaces
++ stat -c %s q
+ awk '{
        count += $NF
            if (count % 10 == 0) {
               percent = count / total_size * 100
               printf "%2d%% [", percent
               for (i=0;i<=percent / 2;i++)
                  printf "→"
               printf "→"

               printf "]\r"
            }
         }
         END { print "" }' total_size=5242880 count=0
 0% [→→]
```

See the first one? That works fine, which executes `cp -- q file`.  Now, the next one, `cp -- q 'file\' 'with\' spaces`   how do I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `"$@"`

man bash:

```
When  the expansion  occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a
separate word.  That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1"  "$2"  ...
```

In your case, use this form:

```
strace -q -ewrite cp -- "$@" | ...
```

Comment: `strace -q -ewrite cp -- "$@" | ...` ?